# Return list of terms instead of list of strings

Tags: list, problog

I have a function ...

```
@problog_export('+str', '-list')
def str2hl(line):
    .....
    fact = [f'{k}:{v}' for k,v in kv.items() ]
    return fact
```

the problem is that it returns :

```
 ["word:the", "pos:det", "dep:det"]
```

instead of :

```
[word:the, pos:det, dep:det]
```

how do I force it to return terms rather than strings !!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out,  Term()

```
fact = [Term(f'{k}:{v}') for k,v in kv.items() ]
```